# If the order of an element of a product group is finite, then the components order divides the order of the element.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A_1,\cdots, A_n$ be groups. Then $A_1\times \cdots \times A_n$ is a group defined in the obvious way.Suppose $ord(g)$ is finite where $g\in A_1\times \cdots \times A_n$ and $g=(a_1,\cdots a_n)$. Then $ord(a_i)|ord(g)$ for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$.

Is this true? How do I prove it?

Comment: If $m=ord(g)$, then $a_i^m = 1$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. So...?

Comment: It would improve your Question to add some context.  Where did the problem come from?  Is it a building block to some result?  Where did your investigation run into a difficulty?  If all else fails, show that you've worked through a small example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Note $g^p=e$ (the identity of $A_1 \times \dots A_n$) if and only if $a_i^p = e_i$ (the identity of $A_i$) for $i=1, \dots, n$.  Now suppose ord$(a_i)=q \leq p$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The order of each element $(g,h)\in G×H$ is $\operatorname {lcm}(\mid g\mid,\mid h\mid)$.